# Finding $a$ in $g^a\bmod p$ in Diffie-Hellman

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm

This might be a silly question but I am unable to wrap my mind around it. In Diffie-Hellman can we find $a$ when $A = g^a\bmod p$, given we know $A$, $g$ and $p$?